# PHP Webdriver Chrome not starting and loading for very long time

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2

I have installed `php-webdriver/webdriver` version "1.7.*" through composer and trying to start chrome driver on amazon ec2 server.

```php
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;

putenv('webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver');

$desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$desiredCapabilities->setCapability('acceptSslCerts', false);
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36';
$chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
$chromeOptions->addArguments(
    array_merge([
        '--headless',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--no-sandbox',
        'user-agent=' . $userAgent,
    ], $headers));
$desiredCapabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $chromeOptions);
echo "reached\n";
$driver = ChromeDriver::start($desiredCapabilities);
$driver->get('https://www.example.com');
sleep(5);
$currentURL = $driver->getCurrentURL();
echo $currentURL;
```

When I am running from command line its working fine.

```
php index.php
```

But when I am trying to run this same file through command line internally by hitting api file from endpoint `https://api.example.com/api.php`

```php
$result = shell_exec("cd /path/to/root-of-site/; php index.php");
echo $result;
```

or

```php
$result = shell_exec("php /path/to/root-of-site/index.php");
echo $result;
```

Its reaching till the code `echo "reached\n";` but not starting the chrome driver at all and not throwing any error also but showing the process on ec2.

```
apache    1074  1073  2 04:57 ?        00:00:00 /path/to/chromedriver --port=9515
apache    1082  1074  0 04:57 ?        00:00:00 [chrome] <defunct>
```

Really appreciate the solution.

Comment: Did you also run the selenium standalone server?

Comment: No, I just installed chrome on aws ec2 and uploaded chromedriver and just pointing it using putenv().

Comment: It's [this](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver), correct? Which version of `php-webdriver/webdriver` are you using?

Comment: Yes, this is the one and version is `1.7.*`

Comment: `just pointing it using putenv()`, what path did you use? can you share that as well? And for this `$result = shell_exec("cd path/to/root-of-site/; php index.php");` can you use absolute path for `php`? Also you might not need `cd path/to/root-of-site/` if you use the absolute path directly at `index.php` like `/path/to/root-of-site/index.php`.

Comment: I am pointing it to chromdriver `putenv('webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver')` and I tried both ways `shell_exec("cd path/to/root-of-site/; php index.php")` and `shell_exec("php path/to/root-of-site/index.php")`